# Why is my button not calling the function again?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, button

I have been trying to create a button to call a function again in order to display a new HTML paragraph, but it won't do that for some reason.

I tried to put a function call on the button in my JS file, but the button doesn't change anything when I click it.  It all just stays the same.

This is towards the end of the HTML, where I created the button:

```
<p>&#8220;We labour at our daily work more ardently and thoughtlessly than is necessary to sustain our life because it is even more necessary not to have leisure to stop and think. Haste is universal because everyone is in flight from himself.&#8221;</p>
<p>&#8220;One should die proudly when it is no longer possible to live proudly.&#8221;</p>
    </div>
    <button class="button">Thus Spoke Nietzsche</button>
<script src="randomize.js"></script>
</body>
```

And this is the JS:

```
"use strict";
const quotes = document.querySelectorAll("p");

const randomize = function() {
    let num = (Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(quotes.length)) - 1);
    let quote = quotes.item(num).innerHTML;
  return quote;
}
const run = function(){
  let randomQuote = randomize();
  let passage = document.getElementById('quotes');
  passage.innerHTML = randomQuote;
  return console.log(randomQuote);
}
const newQuote = document.querySelector('.button');
newQuote.addEventListener('click', run());
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Should be `newQuote.addEventListener('click', run);` without the `()` after `run`. You want to pass a reference to the function, not the result of calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

So at least part of the issue is this:

`newQuote.addEventListener('click', run());`

Which should just be:

`newQuote.addEventListener('click', run);`

**addEventListener** expects the second argument you give it to be a function.  That will be the function it executes when **newQuote** is clicked.  But when you say **run()** (with the parenthesis) you're actually **invoking** the run function and giving the result to **addEventListener** which in this case would be **undefined**.

There may be more issues, but I didn't have time to actually create a code pen and go over it thoroughly, but that was the first thing that stood out to me.